# How do I convert Travis CI configuration to GitHub Actions and test with several versions of Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, travis-ci, github-actions

We have been using Travis CI for about 5 years now, but we have problems recently and their support doesn't help. I'm thinking about using GitHub Actions instead. We use Travis CI to test our code with 4 versions of Python (3.6 to 3.9), and I want to do the same with GitHub Actions. Here is our `.travis.yml` file:

```sh
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
  - "3.9"
sudo: required
dist: bionic
addons:
  postgresql: "9.6"
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'create user pguser;' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'alter user pguser createdb; ' -U postgres
install:
  - cp env.ini.tests env.ini
  - pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
  - pip freeze
  - pwd
  - lsb_release -a
script:
  - cd speedy/net
  - python tests_manage.py test # python -W error::DeprecationWarning tests_manage.py test
  - cd ../match
  - python tests_manage.py test # python -W error::DeprecationWarning tests_manage.py test
  - cd ../composer
  - python tests_manage.py test # python -W error::DeprecationWarning tests_manage.py test
  - cd ../mail
  - python tests_manage.py test # python -W error::DeprecationWarning tests_manage.py test
```

I read about GitHub Actions and I'm trying to create a file `.github/workflows/main.yml`, but I don't know how to define it. How do I define this file to run tests with GitHub Actions? In general I want to convert our `.travis.yml` configuration to GitHub Actions.

This is the `.github/workflows/main.yml` file I'm starting with:

```sh
name: GitHub Actions Speedy Net
on: [push]
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by GitHub!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo " The ${{ github.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Python versions

.travis.yml

```yaml
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
  - "3.9"
```

.github/workflows/main.yml

```yaml
jobs:
  tests:
    ...
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9]
    steps:
      - name: Setup Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
```

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python

## 2. PostgreSQL service

Note the `trust` requirements are specific to your project.
From https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres, for other readers:

> **Note 1:** It is not recommended to use [`trust`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html) since it allows anyone to connect without a password, even if one is set (like via `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`). For more information see the PostgreSQL documentation on [*Trust Authentication*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html).

### PostgreSQL 9.6

.travis.yml

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.6"
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'create user pguser;' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'alter user pguser createdb; ' -U postgres
```

.github/workflows/main.yml

```yaml
jobs:
  tests:
    ...
    steps:
      ...
      - run: |
          sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
          wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.6
          sudo sed -i 's/local   all             postgres                                peer/local   all             postgres                                trust/' /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
          sudo sed -i 's|host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5|host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust|' /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
          ! docker stop $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=postgres)
          sudo sed -i 's/port = 5433/port = 5432/' /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
          sudo service postgresql start
      - run: psql --version
      - run: |
          psql -c 'create user pguser;' -U postgres
          psql -c 'alter user pguser createdb; ' -U postgres
```

### PostgreSQL 12

.github/workflows/main.yml

```yaml
jobs:
  tests:
    ...
    steps:
      ...
      - run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
          sudo sed -i 's/local   all             postgres                                peer/local   all             postgres                                trust/' /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
          sudo sed -i 's|host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5|host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust|' /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
          ! docker stop $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=postgres)
          sudo sed -i 's/port = 5433/port = 5432/' /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
          sudo service postgresql start
      - run: psql --version
      - run: |
          psql -c 'create user pguser;' -U postgres
          psql -c 'alter user pguser createdb; ' -U postgres
```

### PostgreSQL 13

.github/workflows/main.yml

```yaml
jobs:
  tests:
    ...
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
      ...
      - run: psql --version
      - run: |
          psql -c 'create user pguser;' -U postgres
          psql -c 'alter user pguser createdb; ' -U postgres
        env:
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
```

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/creating-postgresql-service-containers